# Even after downloading STS Spring not showing in Eclipse(MARS)

Tags: eclipse, spring

[Here's the version of Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUKbM.png)
Hi i am learning Spring and i tried to install Spring STS from Eclipse Marketplace, it got installed successfully , but i'm not able to see the Spring option under **file-> new** nor under **Window-> perspective**.
Even restarted a few times.
What could be the problem?

Comment: You can try to uninstal eclipse mars and download and  install only Sts

Comment: @Georges van houtte I need it with my Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of java you are using , if its **1.5** and above then only it supports and how did you install it ?
If you can tell that in specific we can help .

Comment: My Java jdk  version is 1.7.0_79 and i downloaded as plugin from Eclipse market place within Eclipse.

Comment: Which Eclipse ?

Comment: Eclipse Mars , also added the image in my question

Comment: Then fine , about  these things , now i have similar things and I just went to the Eclipse market place and draged the sts from there to my Eclipse workspace that worked for me , try it out